# How to modify a GraphQL variable in a contract during the Provider Verification? [Pact-JS]

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, graphql-js, pact

I have a Pact file that looks like following:

```
{
  "consumer": {
    "name": "UI"
  },
  "provider": {
    "name": "GraphQL API"
  },
  "interactions": [
    {
      "description": "Delete item request",
      "providerState": "Atleast one item exists",
      "request": {
        "method": "POST",
        "path": "/",
        "headers": {
          "content-type": "application/json"
        },
        "body": {
          "operationName": null,
          "query": "mutation ($itemId: ID!) { \n                  removeItem(id: $itemId) {    \n                    item {    \n                      id     \n                      __typename  \n                    }    \n                    __typename \n                  }\n                }",
         "variables": {
            "itemId": "item-c9b1f276-3748-4be3-915d-ec01ccbc2197"
          }
        },
        "matchingRules": {
          "$.body.query": {
            "match": "regex",
            "regex": "mutation\\s*\\(\\$itemId:\\s*ID!\\)\\s*\\{\\s*removeItem\\(id:\\s*\\$itemId\\)\\s*\\{\\s*plan\\s*\\{\\s*id\\s*__typename\\s*\\}\\s*__typename\\s*\\}\\s*\\}"
          },
          "$.body.variables.itemId": {
            "match": "type"
          }
        }
      },
      "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "headers": {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "body": {
          "data": {
            "removeItem": {
              "item": {
                "id": "item-c9b1f276-3748-4be3-915d-ec01ccbc2197",
                "__typename": "Item"
              },
              "__typename": "ItemPayload"
            }
          }
        },
        "matchingRules": {
          "$.body.data.removeItem.item.id": {
            "match": "type"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "metadata": {
    "pactSpecification": {
      "version": "2.0.0"
    }
  }
}
```

Before the Pact Verification, I want to provide a **Valid itemId value** which is a GraphQL variable.

In above JSON, its located  `interactions > request > body > variables > itemId`

One Option I tried was Using the `requestFilters` option ([Pact-JS-modify-requests-prior-to-verification-request-filters](https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-js/#modify-requests-prior-to-verification-request-filters)),
However, I am not able to understand how GraphQL variable can be modified?

Or If there is any other Verification option that can be of use?

Answer (score 0):

The `requestFilter` capability uses raw Express JS middleware and makes no assumption about the incoming request payload content type. Thus, you will need to parse the body however makes sense for your request. For example, to extract a JSON payload you could do something like the following (tested on the GraphQL contract against the e2e provider in the Pact JS repository):

```
  requestFilter: (req, _res, next) => {
    if (req.path.match("/graphql")) {
      // Body is NOT automatically converted to JSON or any specific type
      // you need to extract the contents and parse
      let chunks = []
      req.on("data", function(chunk) {
        chunks.push(chunk)
      })
      req.on("end", function() {
        // Request upload complete, convert to a string and parse into JSON
        req.body = JSON.parse(Buffer.concat(chunks).toString())

        // req.body is now JSON, manipulate as needed
        console.log("Body as JSON:", req.body)
        next()
      })
    } else {
      next()
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Matthew! Do you have a full working code? The test just times-out as it tries extracting the contents of req object while collecting chunks of "data"

Comment: Apologies, I haven't got an example for you. Could you please raise an issue with a repro ducible example that we can use to improve/fix (the issue template should guide you to code you can modify and share)?